# insert() not available for QMap variable

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

In my class I have an attribute

```
QMap<QString, QMap<QString, QString>> a;
```

Inside a method of the class I do this:

```
QString s;
QMap<QString, QString> m;
QMap<QString, QMap<QString, QString>> m2;
m.insert(s, s);
m2.insert(s,m);

a.insert(s,m);
```

---

QUESTION: The insert on "m2" works while the insert on "a" gives me a compilation error.

Why?
m2 and a are of the same type.

---

The compilation error:

```
error: passing ‘const QMap<QString, QMap<QString, QString> >’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  529 |   tqMap.insert(s,m);
      |                   ^

----------------------------------------------------
/opt/Qt/5.13.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qmap.h:704: note:   in call to ‘QMap<K, V>::iterator QMap<K, V>::insert(const Key&, const T&) [with Key = QString; T = QMap<QString, QString>]’
  704 | Q_INLINE_TEMPLATE typename QMap<Key, T>::iterator QMap<Key, T>::insert(const Key &akey, const T &avalue)
      |                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
------------------------------------------------------
error: no matching member function for call to 'insert'
---------------------------------------------------------
/opt/Qt/5.13.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qmap.h:586: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const QMap<QString, QMap<QString, QString> >', but method is not marked const
-----------------------------------------------------------
/opt/Qt/5.13.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qmap.h:587: candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If `a` is member of a class and the method is `const` then `this` is pointing to a `const` qualified instance and hence all member variables (e.g. `a`) are `const` as well in this moment. Only local variables (e.g. `m2`) are not `const` if not explicitly `const` qualified. This would match what I can read from the reported errors. However, it's just guessing as long as you do not expose a [mcve].

Comment: The problem is probably in attempt to change `a` member variable in a const function. You are not allowed to do that. You should either make the function non const, or declare `a` as mutable, like: `mutable QMap<QString, QMap<QString, QString>> a;`